# Find closest valid global date from local date and time zone using Noda Time

Tags: .net, nodatime

Given a time zone, I need to check whether a specific instant is included in a day range and a local time range. So let's say the time zone is `Europe/Paris`, the day range is `2020-03-01 to 2020-03-31`, and the local time range is `02:30 to 03:30`. So in this example, the goal would be to find out whether the given instant occurs any day of march 2020 between 02:30 and 03:30.

The thing is, on the day `2020-03-29` in this time zone, daylight savings are applied at `02:00` and the clock skips to `03:00`, so the local time range `02:00 to 03:00` does not actually exist.

I would like to handle this case by shifting the time range to `03:00 to 03:30` for this specific day, `03:00` being the closest valid time ahead of `02:30` given the time zone. I know of `DateTimeZone.AtLeniently(LocalDateTime)`, but it does not work as expected:

```cs
var localDate = new LocalDateTime(2020, 03, 29, 02, 30);
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Europe/Paris"];
ZonedDateTime globalDate = timeZone.AtLeniently(localDate);
Console.WriteLine(globalDate); // 2020-03-29T03:30:00 Europe/Paris (+02)
                                                ^
```

As you can see, `AtLeniently` shifts the time by 1 full hour (shifted forward by the duration of the "gap", as stated in [the documentation](https://nodatime.org/3.0.x/api/NodaTime.DateTimeZone.html#NodaTime_DateTimeZone_AtLeniently_NodaTime_LocalDateTime_)), so the parsed date is `03:30` instead of `03:00`. I don't want to shift the invalid time by 1 full hour, I would prefer shifting forward to the closest valid time (e.g. `03:00`).

Comment: "I would prefer shifting forward to the closest valid time" - that's why you can specify your own `ZoneLocalMappingResolver`... create one which does what you want, then call `timeZone.ResolveLocal(localDate, resolver)`

Comment: (But this makes it really obvious that we've got a gaping hole in our documentation...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on Jon Skeet's comments, I decided to use a custom `ZoneLocalMappingResolver`. This is our current implementation:

```cs
private ZonedDateTime ResolveLocal(
    LocalDateTime localDate, DateTimeZone timeZone
)
{
    return timeZone.ResolveLocal(
        localDate,
        resolver: mapping => mapping.Count == 0 ?
            // Handle the case where the specified local date is skipped in
            // the time zone by using the next valid date.
            mapping.LateInterval.Start.InZone(mapping.Zone) :
            // Otherwise, use the last available result (single if
            // unambiguous).
            mapping.Last()
    );
}

private bool IsInInterval(
    Instant instant, LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime end,
    DateTimeZone timeZone
)
{
    ZonedDateTime globalStart = this.ResolveLocal(start, timeZone);
    ZonedDateTime globalEnd = this.ResolveLocal(end, timeZone);
    return instant > globalStart.ToInstant() &&
        instant < globalEnd.ToInstant();
}
```

Then:

```cs
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Europe/Paris"];

// instant matches 2020-03-29T03:15:00 Europe/Paris (+02)
var instant = Instant.FromUtc(2020, 03, 29, 01, 15);

// Interval bounds
// start will be translated to 2020-03-29T03:00:00 Europe/Paris (+02)
// end will be translated to 2020-03-29T03:30:00 Europe/Paris (+02)
var start = new LocalDateTime(2020, 03, 29, 02, 30);
var end = new LocalDateTime(2020, 03, 29, 03, 30);

bool isInInterval = this.IsInInterval(instant, start, end, timeZone);
Console.WriteLine(isInInterval); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to solve this problem is to look at things the other way around. Instead of converting the [day + local time range + time zone] into a global time range and comparing it to the given instant, we can convert the instant into a local date time in this time zone, and compare it to the local values.

```cs
DateTimeZone dtz = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[ianaTimeZone];
var globalInstant = Instant.FromUtc(2020, 03, 29, 01, 15); // 2020-03-29T03:15:00 Europe/Paris (+02)
LocalDateTime localDate = globalInstant.InZone(dtz).LocalDateTime;
var localStartDate = new LocalDateTime(2020, 03, 29, 02, 30);
var localEndDate = new LocalDateTime(2020, 03, 29, 03, 30);
Console.WriteLine(localDate > localStartDate && localDate < localEndDate); // true
```

Comment: If you can get away with only converting Instant => ZonedDateTime, that definitely removes that side of the problem. It's worth thinking about corner cases though - if you've got a time range of 01:30 to 02:30, does that mean "any time after 01:30 and before 02:30"? Because if the time zone falls back from 2am to 1am on the target day, then 01:15 (the second time) happens *after* 01:30 (the first time). Definitely worth thinking cases like that through really carefully in terms of what you *want* to happen, ignoring the code, before trying to implement it. And make sure you have tests!

Comment: You are absolutely correct, this implementation does not handle the `03:00 -> 02:00` (winter daylight saving time change) as I would expect it to. Instants within the specified time range should be distributed continuously on the same day. I will look upon the `ZoneLocalMappingResolver` implementation instead.